# how to loop over a table in html and iterate their values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a grid (20 rows and 20 columns ( of squares) ) but struggling with looping on table values to actually make the grid

I provided more info on the html code..

The pictures are provided on the comments

```html
    <body>
        <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
        <form id="sizePicker">
            Grid Height:  <!--- Creating input element to input height --->
            <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> 
            Grid Width: <!--- Creating input element to input width --->
            <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker"> <!--- Creating imput element to input a certain color --->

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"> <tr> <td>  </td>  </tr> </table>
    <!--- Creating the table --->

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```css
    table,
    tr,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    tr {
        height: 20px; //some how this is working as it's the same as 
                      //td when i edit it the td gets edited aswell
        width: 20px;
    }

    td {
        height: 20px; //same as here
        width: 20px;
    }
```

```
    const lTable = document.querySelector("pixelCanvas"); 
    //Selecting my table and storing it in a variable

    let height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight");
    //Storing the value on the input height element
    let width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth");
    //Storing the value of the input width element

    function makeGrid() {

    //This is the main problem i can't figure out how to iterate the value
    // to make the actual grid and give it the event listener

}
```

Comment: My current code : https://imgur.com/a/eCj4ZkZ

Comment: What iam trying to build : https://imgur.com/a/DCnx28g

Comment: @jhpratt I think that's enough ? or should i post the rest of the css code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need a form for this unless you want to submit data to a API.

find a minimal solution for your problem here:

```js
    
    
    function makeGrid() {
      let height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
      //Storing the value on the input height element
      let width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
      //Storing the value of the input width element
      //Selecting my table and storing it in a variable
      const lTable = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas"); 
      //This is the main problem i can't figure out how to iterate the value
      // to make the actual grid and give it the event listener
      for (var i=0; i< height;i++) {
        var row = lTable.insertRow(i);
        for (var j=0; j< width;j++) {
          row.insertCell(j);
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px; 
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="inputHeight">Height</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputHeight" value="0"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="inputWidth">Width</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputWidth" value="0"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Draw" onClick="makeGrid()"></input>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Comment: var row = lTable.insertRow(i);
row.insertCell(j);
Can u explain what u did here ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSalah simplest way to explain would be here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Answer (score 0):

A fiddle that may help you:

https://jsfiddle.net/qh6zjfmw/

Here the function, every cell have data-row and data-col that help you to understand the clicked element, and every cell have .row-number and .col-number to target the correct element to change the class (active/inactive)

```
    makegrid(13,13);

    function makegrid(rows, cols){
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        console.log(r+1);
        $('<div class="row row-'+r+'"></div>').appendTo(".grid");

          for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
            console.log(c+1);
            $('<div class="col col-'+c+'" style="width:'+100/cols+'%; padding-bottom:'+100/cols+'%" data-row="'+r+'"  data-col="'+c+'"></div>').appendTo(".grid .row-"+r);

          }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate this but it's really so complicated for me rightnow and not really the way i want to build it with

Comment: but i will try understanding it latter

Comment: this seems like a bit of an over complicated solution. what is the point of adding jquery to this issue and in such a backwards manner :)?

Comment: you're right, jquery isn't necessary, I don't know why I've figured he have jquery, but the function may work with a little modification also without jquery, just modifing the rows with appendTo with vanilla JS

Comment: either that or using insertRow and insertCell. see my answer above. not that jquery is bad, but this specific solution is hard to understand for a beginner  especially since it uses html as a string